# Can't get params.permit to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm posting a form with these params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXX", "bike_part_id"=>["367", "368"], 
"commit"=>"registrer en [48/1854]
 "controller"=>"services", "action"=>"create", "bike_id"=>"10"}
```

This is the controller code:

```
def create
    @service = Service.new(service_params)
    @service.bike = @bike
    @service.bike_parts = @bike_parts

    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.save!
       #[cut..]
end
```

-

```
   def service_params
      params.permit(:description, :log, :due_date, :bike_id,
                    :user_id, :completed, :bike_part_id
                    )
   end
```

But I keep getting this in the log:

```
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, bike_part_id, commit
```

Why isn't bike_part_id allowed?

Comment: Can you post your form code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For arrays you need to specify to the strong params that an array is to be expected.

```
def service_params
      params.permit(:description, :log, :due_date, :bike_id,
                    :user_id, :completed, bike_part_id: []
                    )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is nested. Please try the following:

```
def service_params
  params.permit(
    :description, :log, :due_date, :bike_id, user_id, :completed, bike_part_id: []
  )
end
```